# How to interpret NaN in Lime SubmodularPick

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, lime

I am creating a visualization that displays the aggregated results of LIME SubmodularPick, basically I plot a histogram of the result as well as a boxplot.
However when I look at the table I notice a lot of values are missing, instead they appear as NaN

Why are there missing values?

Is a missing value due to the fact that the feature wasn't considered in the explanation or was it not important?

If there are all NaN and a few really high scores (0.99) does it mean that the feature is important only in a few cases?